# Can a controller ever accept a null parameter value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

If I had a controller method like so:

```
public ActionResult<Item> GetItem(RequestHeaderBase headers, RequestObject request)
```

Can I always assume that the headers object and request object will be instantiated (not null)?

(I would appreciate any links to deeper reading regarding how this works regardless of the answer)

Here is an example of what I mean

Here I call the request: https://localhost:44360/weatherforecast and you can see the input object has been instantiated despite me not providing the query string.
[image]

Another example, this time with data from the body:
[image]
[image]

In both cases, you can see with my debugging, no matter what the objects are instantiated, even if I don't provide any data in the request.

Now I've seen code that checks if this data is null in some of our applications, I believe this code is irrelevant, and so can be removed.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What are you trying to achieve? If you're trying to access the properties of a request then use `HttpContext.Request` which will be populated as long as the controller invocation came from a HTTP request. (Its possible to call controller logic from application code, but its not recommended).

Comment: Not particularly a problem, I saw some code which checked if one of these parameters was null, so for instance if(request == null)... but as I understand it, the parameters in the http request, from any source will always be instantiated in the controller method, just wanted to confirm I was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is a reference object ( not a value) it will be always instantiated. Each object property will have a default value. This is why any class that are using for action input parameter should have default or parameter less constructor. Otherwise it will cause an exception. Only when object is created,  controller trying to assign values to the object properties according to the http request.  But be carefull, only the top level will be instantiated. If you have another complicated properties inside of this object, they will be instantied and have a default value according to the type. For example, List will be null (default value), not an empty list. Nullable integer property will ne null, not nullable 0, and so on. But you can assign default values you need in the constructor for example.

even if you change the action signature to this

```
public ActionResult<Item> GetItem(RequestHeaderBase headers=null, RequestObject request=null)
```

they still will be instantiated, each property will have a default value according to the type.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I always assume that the headers object and request object will be instantiated (not null)?

No, they can be null.

Comment: Hi do you have an example or a link to some documentation to show me?

Comment: I think you need to read more about HTTP protocol and JSON serialization

Comment: @DubDub please mark the answer as accepted if it's the answer you asked for

Comment: It's not, you haven't given an example or explained why it's the case.

Comment: you asked a yes/no question, and I answered your question.
also, I suggest to you what should you read about. 
which part is not answered, or what's help do you need now?

Comment: I've updated the question with examples that seem to display otherwise. Can you show me in what scenario the 'WeatherForecast' object in my controller method can be null like you say? A link as to where it's specifically stated under what circumstances this would occur.